# Type that converts all the methods on an interface to return promises

Tags: typescript

If I have an interface like

```js
interface foo {
  bar(): string
}
```

I'd like a utility type which converts all of its methods to return promises

```js
type bar = Promised<foo>

/*
interface bar {
  bar(): Promise<string>
}
*/
```

I have started on it and I have gotten this far:

```js
export type PromisesMap<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Promise<T[P]> };
```

But it converts the properties to promises, and not the return types

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
interface Foo {
  bar(): string
}

type Promisify<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => any
    ? (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => Promise<ReturnType<T[K]>>
    : T[K]
};

type FooWithPromises = Promisify<Foo>; // { bar: () => Promise<string>; }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyARnFABQCUAXMgM5hSgDmBAvgQWAJ4AOKABSjoAtsDrAY3ADwAVAHzIAvDgJEA2gGlkoZAGsI3dDGSyAurVlazyCAA9IIACZ1k5AHSeyzOrTghuSmVFf241ZAB+N093b19kATI4EQhIKDo5a3kgpUUhUXEIaQAlVIBXKBBZPiKrTTN5eXDLa3YAbk58Hn40TAB1YDAAC3yxOghXFVHxSRkMdHk25AB6ZZwSMloqYIThMaKGJhBmReQ2IA)

---

We use [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) (as you've already started to do). We check if member is a function and if yes - return function with same arguments and return type wrapped in `Promise`, otherwise preserve member's type ([conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types)). To extract function parameters' and return types we use [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) and [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) utilities.

---

Taking extra step as suggested by @VLAZ and skipping methods which already return `Promise`:

```
interface Foo {
  bar(): string,
  baz(arg: string): Promise<boolean>,
}

type WrapNonPromiseInPromise<T> = T extends Promise<any> ? T : Promise<T>;

type Promisify<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => any
  ? (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => WrapNonPromiseInPromise<ReturnType<T[K]>>
  : T[K]
};

type FooWithPromises = Promisify<Foo>; // { bar: () => Promise<string>, baz: (arg: string) => Promise<boolean> }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyARnFABQCUAXMgM5hSgDmANAUaQF7lnO0MmIZjWQAFKOgC2wOhAA8xTABsIcEAD52+AL4ECYAJ4AHFAHUocYwDl0ICdNkQAkvcky58gCobkAXmQvZAgAD0gQABM6cXcneXVDXwB+QORaBw8FHwBufXwjUxjHOmAYQ29fALxCZABtAGlkUGQAawhDdBhAgF1aLwbu4LCISOjyADpJvjpaBMp-XwSOZBSJqahmGfEyOCkISCg6bwGNeb9fCytbN2KXG8z5ACV9gFcoEC8TLJONZb6Bgg6XL4AxfNCYMzAMAACwyTmiAThJTK8gw6A02WQAHosTgSGRaFQFkUHoIWFp8VxCXwBIwWGdfEiFEp0Kp1L4dEA)

Comment: Argh, I keep forgetting that `Parameters` exists. I thought that you couldn't obtain the parameters of a method in order to copy them. One thing to maybe be wary - if a method returns `Promise<x>` this will wrap it in another and the return type would be `Promise<Promise<x>>`. Since promises flatten, the result should just be `Promise<x>` again. However, might not be an issue, either if it doesn't return a Promise.

Comment: Yes you're right. This can be extended and we can additionally check if return type is already `Promise` or not

Comment: `WrapNonPromiseInPromise` :D For some reason in my brain it makes a lot more sense to call that UnwrapPromise. But that might be because I expect Promises to do that when resolved with a Promise, doesn't really need to be reflected in the type name. At any rate, seems like a solid solution.