# How do I extract all methods' ReturnType<T> of class (while ReturnType<T> and usage seem static)

Tags: typescript, generics, decorator, typescript-generics

I've gone through the docs at typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet

I've searched on here and found two cases of `ReturnType<T>`, but they all seem statically written out, and I know there has to be a way to dynamically read out the response data type.

Example of *close to idea*:

- [Rewrite error catching higher order function to catch async errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325850/rewrite-error-catching-higher-order-function-to-catch-async-errors/62326380#62326380)
- [Type that converts all the methods on an interface to return promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61358692/type-that-converts-all-the-methods-on-an-interface-to-return-promises/61358913#61358913)
- [Is modifying method's return type by decorator possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429068/is-modifying-methods-return-type-by-decorator-possible)

For example:

```
class Idea1 {
    one() { return "one"; }
    two() { return "two"; }
}
class Idea2 {
    do() { return { message: "do-one" }; }
    process() { return { shouldDo: true }; }
}

// similar to the example I've seen
const i1 = new Idea1();
declare type R1 = ReturnType<typeof i1.one>; // string

const i2 = new Idea2();
type R2 = ReturnType<typeof i2.do>;  // { message: string }
```

I know the "typical" way is to extract it via type, but how could I submit a class and get a list of return types?

like (with the classes above)

```
//what I'd love to see
getReturnTypes(Idea1) // [string, string]

//but I could always new it up first then pass it, and then passed in
getReturnTypes(new Idea2()) // [{message: string}, {shouldDo: boolean}]
```

**the main thing is that I want to be able to get method return information**

I'm having a terrible time trying to understand how to programmatically work through this flow. I see the assignment for the type being at a high level on the page, so it makes it odd to write out a new type for each method of class as another type ReturnType.

Help please!

Comment: How do you want to deal with the order? `[{message: string}, {shouldDo: boolean}]` and `[{shouldDo: boolean}, {message: string}]` are not the same

Comment: @HTN, Correct! They are not the same, nor should they be in the example. I'm guessing you're asking because of the typo in the example. I'll fix it. Thank you for the find. As for the order, it doesn't really matter. I was more interested in understanding how to develop against querying a class and extracting the `ReturnType` its methods.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you want to do is impossible, because you'd like to return/use types as values at runtime. However, types are compile-time-only in TS.

See here for more information:
[Returning a Type as a Variable in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263504/returning-a-type-as-a-variable-in-typescript)